# access denied in skechers in python

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, python-requests, webdriver

here is my code i want to extract all data but access is denied https://www.skechers.com/women/shoes/athletic-sneakers/?start=0&sz=168

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import pandas as pd 
import time 
url = 'https://www.skechers.com/women/shoes/athletic-sneakers/?start=0&sz=168'
driver = webdriver.Chrome('D:/chromedriver')
driver.get(url)
pageSource = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(pageSource, 'html.parser')
content= soup.find_all('div',class_='col-6 col-sm-4 col-xl-3 mb-2 mb-md-1 mb-lg-4 px-lg-3') 
skechersshoes=[]
products_elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='product']")
skechersshoes = [product.get_attribute('data-pid') for product in products_elements]

print(skechersshoes)
skechers={

    'productid':skechersshoes
}
skechersshoes.append(skechers)
df = pd.DataFrame(skechersshoes)
print(df.head())
df.to_csv('sskechers.csv')
```

[image]

Comment: You can switch user agents... might help. probably won't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
url = 'https://www.skechers.com/women/shoes/athletic-sneakers/?start=0&sz=168'
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ['enable-automation'])
options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
options.add_argument(
    "user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36")
options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9222")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get(url)
```

Try disabling automation flags and adding user agent